# Android studio lost R after renaming

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

i had a working prototype when at one build i ran into a disk-full problem...
removed the clutter on my HD and tried to re-organize my code a little bit. I didn't found at that moment the tip to force the display of the directory structure of the source tree by dropping a file on a directory of that (otherwise emtpy) tree and did the renaming and shifting by hand.....

grepped over the whole code to change all references, and started studio again, everything compiles, but i got the dreaded "package R does not exist" message...

i went over the archive of that type of question....
no error flags on the xml layout files
i upgraded the ADK SDK to build 22.6,
i removed the whole src/gen tree
i added a new layout
checked that R isn't imported
i cleaned my build and
re-build it

still, it won't compile due to that error
i am at a loss what to try next to get it running again?

Comment: do you have this under source control, like git or something?

Comment: not yet... as i am not comfortable with git i have on the lib parts under mercurial, but not the interface part...

Comment: you've likely got some error somewhere in your xml or manifest.  Check those first. If nothing looks wrong, clean and then build your project.  There's a million threads on this topic - if what works for me doesn't work for you, search a bit more on this site.

Comment: well i am now 4 days on this, i've digged up a fair amount of answers to this sort of question but nothing works so far....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered that if you put something below another thing in the XML like this for example:

```
android:layout_below"@id/something"
```

It will kill your R.

You can fix it by changing the code to this:

```
android:layout_below"@+id/something"
```

This kinda thing has been happening to me a lot lately.

Answer (score 3):

After renaming the package, I had the same issue. I solved it by changing the package attribute in manifest tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.www.main.activity" >
```

Comment: Interesting, indeed i never looked at that, will have to wait the next time the problem arises!

Answer (score 1):

Changes in your Build target also can effect R.java in Eclipse so

Right Click Project >> Properties >> Android >> Select Latest(usually) Android API Platform >> Click OK

I think, you may need to relaunch Android SDK Manager again and install a new item: Android SDK Build-tools.

[image]

After installing this, clean your projects and rebuild.Hope this is helpful.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, i forgot to add it to the list of thinks i tried, it was indeedone of the things i found here... i sort of "solved" the problem, by creating a new project, copying everything over, and it worked.... hell knows why...